# Activity logging system for Ruby on Rails search site

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a horse search site built in Ruby on Rails - FindHorsesForSale.net, and want to build an activity logging system that will tell me:
- how many times a listing appeared in search results
- how many times a listing appeared on a details page
- the click through rate of each position in search results

The app is hosted on Heroku.  Any recommendations on how to build something scalable to answer the questions above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way would be another `Model` for counting hits including a `hit_type` field to differ between hits in search and hits of the profile. The model could look like this:

```
Hit hit_type:string user_agent:string ip:string horse_id:integer`
```

Then you associate the `Hit` Model with the `Horse` model via `has_many` and in the search action you create a new object of `hit`for each found horse and also a new hit Object for each view of the profile. The only difference will be the hit_type which could be "search" and "profile" for example. Then you could write scopes for both in `Hit` Model:

```
scope :searched, where("hit_rype = ?", "search")
scope :viewed, where("hit_type = ?", "view")
```

THen you could easy check the horses views:

```
horse.hits.searched.count # returns count of views
horse.hits.viewed # returns count of profile views
```

Hope this helps you!

// I had a look at your sites. If your doing buisness with your websites you should know about SEO so your found! All your domainnames use camelCase but google doenst recognise camelCase in domainnames, words,... Just a hint

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Creating 20 hits every time a search results page is shown would seem to slow down page load, not something I want to do.  Any suggestions on how to make it perform well?  Perhaps calling everything via delayed_job or something similar?

Comment: Try it, similar tasks dont slow down my applications eaven I ceate 100 Objects every time a page is loaded!